# what does setup.py do?

Tags: software-installation, python

I am not from a computer science background, and I would like to ask how come when I downloaded python packages from github, I have to run setup.py? what does that do to the program and my other system settings?
And also, if I have ran the command 
sudo python setup.py install develop --user on one of the branches, say A, I see that some files contain both .pyc and .py files. If I create a branch from A, say B, I cannot run the above command anymore and all the files in B remain in .pyc Does that mean I cannot run my program in branch B?
Many thanks! Very confused.

Comment: "Computer science" has as much to do with computers as "Astronomy" has to do with telescopes... ;D

Comment: And only do use programs with manual installation via scripts (like setup.py is) if you have not the possibility to use software from the standard repositories or at least a PPA... Both for security (malware risk) and stability (messing up your system) reasons.

Comment: Hi ByteCommander, thanks for your comments, but what if you were to try developing some open source?

Comment: Well, as I said, prefer applications in the repos over PPAs over downloaded .deb-files  over tarballs (archives containing installation data and scripts). Of course, if the software you want to use is not yet available over a more recommended way, you have to get it in a less recommended way. When you want to publish your own software, you should consider creating a PPA or at least packaging your program to a .deb-file.

Comment: Right, I'll have a look more about packaging a program and PPA. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

setup.py is the file that will handle the installation of your packages. you execute it by prefixing it with the python command and by passing install as a parameter, hence, the "python setup.py install".
.pyc are the compiled bytecode of your python code (for faster execution). So if yoou are moving your code, I suggest you take the .py files and remove the old .pyc from the old folder as they will be regenerated after.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, so through running the file setup.py,  .py files are compiled to .pyc?

Comment: No, running setup.py will install the modules you are needing for further development (After installation you can import them to your code). After the installation, you can delete the folder that contains setup.py file as they are now installed.